# If I encrypt only my Home Directory, can someone use a usb to hack my system

Tags: partitioning, encryption

If I encrypt only my Home directory, can a hacker use a USB boot drive to hack my system files and then install hack software, etc. aka still not safe?
I am multi bood hdisk w, mate 19.10

Comment: I think this is not a *buntu specific question. Did you try reading this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41368/ ? A lot of data ends up in swap and /tmp /etc. I think it is trivial to install some backdoor. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: I edited to simply know if the file sys and installed software can be compromised.  I mostly only care about the browser for privacy since it has autofill passwords.  I save most data on a 4th open drive for passing to other partitions.

Comment: Is this computer located in a public place? Do you expect the hacker to break into your home? Does the hacker live in your home? If answer to any of these question is yes, then yes it is not safe.

Comment: Can you define "hack"?  Do you mean take control of your computer?  Steal your documents?  Install malware?

Comment: Yes, hack means install mawlware that can do damage.  I know j can re-install grub on my sys  by USB, so I guess it is possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a comment but also the answer.
Is this computer located in a public place? Do you expect the hacker to break into your home? Does the hacker live in your home? If answer to any of these question is yes, then yes it is not safe.

I added bios password because ful disk encryption with TPM and secure boot was not working..  bios would do the trick.  Cannot undo this easily without me knowing.  And home dir is protected.

Comment: I am glad I could help